# unable to post game score on facebook wall in android using libgdx framework

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx, game-engine

I am just trying to make a game where I need to post game score on facebook wall. And I am following libGDX framework. Below is my test activity that just post my custom message on facebook wall.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String FB_APP_ID = "1452723631660564";
    private static final String FACEBOOK_PERMISSION = "publish_stream";
    private static final int FB_AUTH = 2; // ANY INTEGER VALUE
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook(FB_APP_ID); //
    static String FACEBOOK_UPDATE_MSG;
    static String FACEBOOK_UPDATE_FAILURE;
    static String FACEBOOK_UPDATE_SUCCESS;
    static String FACEBOOK_SIGNIN_FAILED;
    Handler fHandler = new Handler();       

    Map<Object, Object> preferences = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        login("Hello facebook test app");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case FB_AUTH:
            facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
        default:
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }


    public void postMessageOnWall(final String msg) {


        try {

            if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("message", msg);
                        parameters.putString("link", "ANDROID_MARKET_LINK"); // or any other
                                                                                // link
                        parameters.putString("name", "APP/GAME NAME");
                        try {
                            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,
                                    "POST");

                            FACEBOOK_UPDATE_MSG = FACEBOOK_UPDATE_SUCCESS;
                            fHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            FACEBOOK_UPDATE_MSG = FACEBOOK_UPDATE_FAILURE;
                            fHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);

                        }
                    }               

                });

            }   



        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("error-----------", e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }

    }



    final Runnable mUpdateFacebookNotification = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), FACEBOOK_UPDATE_MSG,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void login(final String msg) {
        /*String access_token = preferences.getString("facebook_access_token",
                null);*/

        String access_token = (String) preferences.get("facebook_access_token");
        long expires = 0;
        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(10000000l);
        }
        /*
         * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
         */
        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream","read_stream", "offline_access" },
                    FB_AUTH, new DialogListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            /*preferences.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            preferences.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            preferences.flush();*/

                            preferences.put("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                            preferences.put("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            if (msg != "")
                                postMessageOnWall(msg);
                            else
                                OpenFbPage();
                        }

                        private void OpenFbPage() {



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                            FACEBOOK_UPDATE_MSG = FACEBOOK_SIGNIN_FAILED;
                            fHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                            FACEBOOK_UPDATE_MSG = FACEBOOK_SIGNIN_FAILED;
                            fHandler.post(mUpdateFacebookNotification);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                        }
                    });
        } 

    }

}
```

I am not getting any exception/error in above code, but it also doesn't post my custom message on my facebook wall. It just opens an fb application and loading alert over that, nothing else. When I debug that, it neither reach on thread's run() method of postMessageOnWall() , nor I get any response defined in same method. 
Please guide me where I am wrong. I know I write my whole code related to facebook post in single activity, but it just an test application. Once it is successful, I will segregate the logic.

Answer (score 1):

among hundreds of things badly wrong with this example, you are not starting the thread (by calling `start`). If you had actually tried to make a small, self-contained example, as you should have, you would have found out on your own.